# How to get the ID of a dynamic element when loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

***VIEW***

```
$1 = array('value'=>'1|3','class'=>'temp_stok', 'id'=>'st1');
$2 = array('value'=>'2','class'=>'temp_stok','id'=>'st2');
$3 = array('value'=>'5|7','class'=>'temp_stok','id'=>'st3');

echo form_input($1);echo form_input($2); echo form_input($3);
```

i want to split every value content '|'

```
var id = $('.temp_stok').id();
var val_id = $('#st'+id).val();

if(val_id.indexOf('|') >= 1)
{ var _stok = val_id.split('|');
  var stok1 = _stok[0]; var stok1 = _stok[1]; }
```

but the problem is get the id. How can i get id ?

Comment: How exactly does an `.temp_stok` element look like (HTML)? jQuery objects don't have an `.id` function (is this jQuery?).

Comment: yes. but if i use .attr('id') it's only read the first one

Comment: Well, since `.id()` doesn't exist, it reads no ID at all, so it's certainly not better than `.attr` :P You only get the first one because that's what `.attr` does (read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)). So... what do you want to do? Do you want to process each `.temp_stok` element and execute the code for each of them? You can do this, you might have guessed it, with `.each`: https://api.jquery.com/each/ . See also https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zpTfN/)):

```
// Select all inputs that contains | in it's value
var inputsWithPipe = $("input[value*='|']");

// Then loop all the inputs and split
$.each(inputsWithPipe, function(k, v){
    var arr = v.value.split('|');
    console.log(arr); // an array of numbers
});
```

Now you may use each `arr` array as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the id of the element you are interested in:

```
var id = $('.temp_stok').attr('id');
```